# NodeJs commands not working properly on Ubuntu 14.04, nodemon, forever and node

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-14.04

NodeJs is latest version, npm is latest and they both work kinda.

My problem is, that when i try to run `nodemon exampleFile.js`, it returns nothing and nothing happends, same with forever, `forever start exampleFile.js`, i tried to install them both globally too, but result is the same.

I tried restarting server, still nothing!

1 more problem, when i run `node exampleFile.js`, that doesnt work, acts like the same, returns nothing but when i run `nodejs exampleFile.js`, it works perfectly!

exampleFile content:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(5555);
var login = io.of('/login').on('connection', function (socket) {});
var notify = io.of('/notifications').on('connection', function (socket) { });
var chat = io.of('/chat').on('connection', function (socket) { });
```

If anyone here can help me with my broken server and how to fix it, help me out!

OS Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I'm trying to diagnose the source of the issue here: https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/422 can you post on the github issue because I can't replicate this issue at all (yet).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had similar symptoms to you, npm was working but things like forever weren't doing anything - no errors, *nothing*.

After I [read here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server) that you are supposed to use **nodejs** to install, i.e.

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

I thought that maybe that had messed things up somehow, but after a few reinstalls... no dice :(

### What did work

Apparently you need to **link node with nodejs**, like this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node
```